# React-Native unable to put a video to Amplify storage from local file system

Tags: android, react-native, aws-amplify

Given the following:

```js
  const path = 'file:///data/user/0/com.thing.place/cache/VisionCamera-20220520_1215171796142274516288565.mp4'

  const uploadVideo = async () => {
    const timestamp = Date.now()
    const filename = 'blablablah'

    // tried with and without the following:
    // const response = await fetch(path)
    // console.log(response) // fetch.umd.js:600 Not allowed to load local resource: {path}
    // const blob = await response.blob()
    //    

    // below is never triggered?
    const upload = Storage.put(filename, path, {
      contentType: 'video/mp4',
      resumable: true,

      completeCallback: (event) => {
        console.log(`Successfully uploaded ${event.key}`)
      },
      progressCallback: (progress) => {
        console.log(`Uploaded: ${progress.loaded}/${progress.total}`)
      },
      errorCallback: (error) => {
        console.error('Unexpected error while uploading', error)
      },
    })
  }
```

This is never erroring out or failing, it just never starts.  What is missing here and or how do we upload the file from the local file system cached storage?

- Permissions granted, check
- S3 policies in place, check
- Amplify configured, check
- file able to be viewed in *react-native-video*, check
- file created and stored via *react-native-vision-camera*

As always any and all direction is greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the debugger is running via debug in the in-app menu, the fetch call:

```js
const response = await fetch(path)
```

...fails silently, and the code never begins the upload.